# most efficient way to compare short string with small dictionary (parsing)

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to optimize my simple C interpretter that I made just for fun, I am doing parsing like this - firstly I parse file into tokens inside doubly linked list, then I do syntax and semantic analysis.
I want to optimize function with this prototype:

bool parsed_keyword(struct token *, char dictionary[][]);

Inside the function I basically call strcmp against *all keywords* and edit token type.
This of course lead to 20 strcmp calls for each string that is being parsed (almost).

I was thinking Rabin-Karp would be best, but it sounds to me like it isn't best suited for this job (matching one word against small dictionary).
What would be the best algoritm to do this work? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: When it comes to `n = 20` optimization should be the least of your concerns. Virtually any order polynomial function is fine for your needs.

Comment: According to Niklaus Wirth, that *is* the most efficient way to do things, when you're looking up local symbols in a compiler/interpreter.  He even did testing to make sure.  (Of course, his metric might be different from yours, but his metric is a really nice one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash table would probably be my choice for this particular problem. It will provide `O(1)` lookup for a table of your size. A trie would also be a good choice though.

But, the simplest to implement would be to place your words in an array alphabetically, and then use `bsearch` from the C library. It should be almost as fast as a hash or trie, since you are only dealing with 30 some words. It might actually turn out to be faster than a hash table, since you won't have to compute a hash value.

Steve Jessop's idea is a good one, to layout your strings end to end in identically sized char arrays.

```
const char keywords[][MAX_KEYWORD_LEN+1] = {
 "auto", "break", "case", /* ... */, "while"
};

#define NUM_KEYWORDS sizeof(keywords)/sizeof(keywords[0])

int keyword_cmp (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp(a, b);
}

const char *kw = bsearch(word, keywords, NUM_KEYWORDS, sizeof(keywords[0]),
                         keyword_cmp);

int kw_index = (kw ? (const char (*)[MAX_KEYWORD_LEN+1])kw - keywords : -1);
```

If you don't already have it, you should consider acquiring a copy of [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811). Because of its cover, it is often referred to as *The Dragon Book*.

Comment: If you pad all the words out with nul bytes to the length of the longest one, then the binary search becomes particularly simple because you can lay the strings end to end - no second indirection. Since they're keywords, the list won't change very often.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I added your implementation suggestion to the answer, regards

Comment: Unrelated, but of all the ridiculous covers for comp sci books (dinosaur os book; not to mention all of the o'reilly animal books) that compilers book has the coolest cover ever.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c: Thanks for reminding me about the cover, I updated the answer. Regards

Comment: Nice answer, haven't really thought of this trick. Thank you.

Comment: @AoeAoe: Thanks for accepting my answer, +1 on your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for efficiency I would say that Rabin Karp is not your best bet, and your best efficiencies would be found with Boyer-Moore, though it is a fair bit more difficult to implement.

If you are doing this for fun, honestly I don't think there is any need to optimize as those calls should still run in a pretty short amount of time and you don't really need it to run at industry speed.

If you are looking to play around with string matching algorithms, which is a cool and useful goal I would suggest looking into the KMP algorithm and the Boyer-Moore algorithm, both of which will teach you a lot during implementation.

There are of course other more straightforward methods, like dictionary lookups and simple binary search etc..., but those don't really optimize for the fact that you are dealing with strings and string comparison is a really interesting field that you will inevitably run into at some point.

Comment: Nah, boyer moore is terribly ineffective in this specific case (matching against more than just one word), probably as inefficient as naive matching algo.
Yes, I'm doing that for fun only, otherwise I would probably not care at all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your keywords aren't changing, this sounds like the right case for a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). A perfect hash function maps inputs to integers (like a regular hash function), but with no collisions.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#External_links) has links to several perfect hash generators, including [GNU gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html).

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that comes to mind when doing lookups is to just use a sorted array of keyboards, and do a binary search on them.

Answer (score 0):

If the set of keywords is fixed, you can use perfect hashing, for example using [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/). This requires only constant work and a single string comparison, thus being probably faster than other approaches.